# After Eclipse-Update, refactor-rename doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

After Updating to 4.23.0 (2022-03), refactor-rename doesn't work anymore. When I open the refactoring menu, the option "rename" shows up but it doesn't rename the variable in other places. The shortcut doesn't work either. What can I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's actually a bug in Lombok, as detailed [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579168).

Updating to Lombok version 1.18.23 resolved the issue for me. It's currently available here: https://projectlombok.org/download-edge)

Comment: A new release is imminent (latest: This weekend), FYI :)

Comment: Yes, that is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

I updates the STS latest version and its worked foe me ,
CTL+ALT+P is the defalt command
below is details of my STS

Version: 4.15.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202206171354

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2022 VMware, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit https://spring.io/tools

This product includes software developed by the
Eclipse Foundation https://www.eclipse.org

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation https://www.apache.org

Lombok v1.18.23 "Edgy Guinea Pig" - 2022-03-16 is installed. https://projectlombok.org/